# Filter output of git diff-tree based on file extension

Tags: linux, git, unix, git-diff-tree

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

gives me the list all the files that were committed for that SHA.

I am looking for a way to get a list of files with only .xml or .html extensions.

I checked the documentation page - [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#:%7E:text=This%20format%20lists%20the%20commits,Defaults%20to%20diff.) and couldn't see any option.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-- <path> [<otherpath> ...]` for this :

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -- *.xml *.html
```

Be sure to put it at the end of the command, with no options behind it, since git will treat anything past it as paths.

Doc from the git log page [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ltpathgt82308203), but this is usable for a lot of display commands.

Comment: depending on your shell : you may want to put quotes around `"*.xml"` and `"*.html"`, so that they don't get expanded before executing the git command.